# Why when I change a grid to flex it doesn't work?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm working on a challenge that is based on a grid container this grid contains 3 cards and they are displayed horizontally.

**THE PROBLEM**

I have a class called .grid-container which has these CSS properties:

```
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
```

so in my media query, I did this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 900px) {
  .grid-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

As you can see I changed the grid to flex with column direction but when I change screen resolutions it doesn't take effect.

If you want to check out the site and source code:

Live site: https://themax370.github.io/3-column-card-component/ 
Repository: https://github.com/TheMax370/3-column-card-component

Comment: you could also do this reset `grid-template-columns: 1fr`. ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Which would run into just the same issue.

Comment: @connexo which is ? did i mis something aside building a grid with a single column ? (if it is about specifity, answer was given)

Comment: Yes, the specificity issue. In their case, they fail to override `display`, in your suggestion (given it was the only change) they'd fail on overriding `grid-template-columns`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [original rule](https://github.com/TheMax370/3-column-card-component/blob/main/styles.css#L53) is more specific:

```
main .grid-container { ... }
```

beats [this one](https://github.com/TheMax370/3-column-card-component/blob/6767c829e20049670e33249c14d1560a7c5053cb/styles.css#L97)

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 900px) {
  .grid-container { ... }
}
```

every time, because media queries **don't affect the specificity** of rules, **at all**.

When two or more rules contradict for an element, the more **specific** one wins. That is **the** basic CSS mechanism.

So when using media queries, always make sure

1. that your media queries come **after** the original rules they are meant to overwrite (which you did);
2. that the rules you want to override have **at least the same specificity** as the original rules (which you failed in).

Comment: I forgot to place the main before the grid-contianer class

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `main` before `.grid-container`

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 900px) {
    main .grid-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

Comment: [CSS Specifity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) may be help you

Comment: I thought I have placed the "main" but I realized now I didn't thanks